# Class not found when migrating to DDEV from Nitro

Tags: craft3, nitro

I'm migrating from Nitro to DDEV, and on this particular project I'm running im some problems with a custom module.

I'm getting this error:

Error
Class "modules\bcsmodule\services\TimeslotService" not found

It's only occurring in DDEV. Everything works fine in Nitro.

I tried ddev exec composer dump-autoload

This is the code:

```
<?php 
namespace modules\bcsmodule\variables;

use craft\elements\Entry;
use modules\bcsmodule\services\TimeslotService;
use modules\eventmailermodule\EventMailerModule;

class BCSVariable {
   public function test(){
        return 'blabla';
   }

   /**
    * Gets all timeslots available for training and for current user
    */
   public function getAvailableTimeslots(Entry $training): Array
   {
      return (new TimeslotService($training))
         ->allTimeslots()
         ->filterByUser()
         ->filterByMaxUsers()
         ->get();
   }
```

```
<?

namespace modules\bcsmodule\services;

use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use yii\base\Component;

class TimeslotService extends Component
{
    protected $user = null;
    protected $training;
    protected $timeslots;
...
```

Comment: Wild guess here, but can you rule out case issues? I’m looking at `BCSVariable` (not `BcsVariable`) and wondering how everything’s registered and if each container might handle filename casing differently.

Comment: @MattStein Well, the test() variable is working just fine. Is there something about the TimeslotService ddev does not like? Or do you mean I should try BcsVariable as class name?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ensure your directory structure matches your namespacing, so it should be:

```
- Module.php
- variables/BCSVariable.php
- services/TimeslotService.php
```

Services are generally registered as components on the module, rather than being instantiated directly.

```php
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $this->setComponents([
        'timeslot' => TimeslotService::class,
    ]);

    // ...
}
```

Which can then be called as follows.

```php
Module::getInstance()->timeslot->get();
```

See the docs at https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/services.html

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. my problem was that TimeslotService was opened with shorthand PHP so like

```
<?
```

DDEV doesn't like this by default so you should always just open with the full  opening tag. Hopefully I can help others with this information.

```
<?php
```